# Multiple processors trying to update the same row in database

Tags: c#, sql-server, azure-functions, dapper

I have an Azure function app that triggers when data is enqueued to a service bus queue. In the Azure function, I implemented a charging method. First I get the particular row from the database and check the account points.

`SELECT * FROM UsersAccountPoints WHERE UserId = @UserId`

Then I update the points.

```
UPDATE UsersAccountPoints
SET FundsChange = @ChargeAmount, FundsAmount -= @ChargeAmount
WHERE UserId = @UserId
```

When I run this on local, it runs perfectly fine. But when I deploy it on Azure, the function app starts scaling. Then parallel processors start updating the same row of the UsersAccountPoints table, giving me confusing results.

Then I tried `UPDLOCK`.

```
SELECT *
FROM UsersAccountPoints WITH (UPDLOCK)
WHERE UserId = @UserId
```

But this also gives me the same result. I use the Azure premium function, SQL Server database, and Dapper for ORM. Is there a better way to handle this kind of scenario than `UPDLOCK`?

Comment: Typically when you build queue processors which can run in parallel, you use a stored procedure or similar to pull the item(s) of the queue you are planning to handle and you immediately set them in progress while you hold a lock on them. And all processors should ignore any in progress items. You then need a mechanism to check for in progress items which have been in progress for too long in case the process dies or similar.

Comment: I would look at the  UserId parameter to make 100% sure there are no implicit conversions going on. Ie is  UserId a string or int?  If string is it varchar or nvarchar. Make sure the code is the same as the database.